# Break function from inside jquery foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function like below

```
function funk()
{
    $.each(game, function(i, curr) {
        check = curr["value"];
        if(check=="") {
            alert("Please Fill");
            return false;
        }

    });
    alert("success");
    return false;

}
```

So basically when Function `funk` is called , When `check is null` , I want to alert and exit from the function.But I have strange problem where , After `$.each` , `alert("succes")` too is called;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you break out of the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop by returning false, doesn't mean it's going to break out of the wrapping function.

You're going to have to set a variable so you know when your [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop was intentionally terminated early:

```
function funk() {
  var broke = false;
  $.each(game, function(i, curr) {
    check = curr["value"];
    if(check=="") {
      alert("Please Fill");
      broke = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!broke)
    alert("success");

  return false;
}
```